# How do you select 3 adjacent rows with emphasis on the lower values in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, rows

I'm trying to figure out how to select 3 adjacent rows from a table with a price < current item price. The problem is that if I'm selecting the first, second, or third row in the table, I need to select three adjacent rows **around** the current item. Emphasis needs to be put on the lower price items, for example, if I'm selecting the third row from the table, I need to select the first two rows and the fourth row. Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM temp_db_cart 
      WHERE airport='$airport' 
        AND people='$people' 
        AND price < '$price' 
      ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 3
     ) 
ORDER BY price ASC
```

Sample data:

```
+---------------+---------+--------+-------+
|  hotel_name   | airport | people | price |
+---------------+---------+--------+-------+
| Days Inn      | MLB     |      1 |   109 |
| Holiday Inn   | MCO     |      2 |   149 |
| Americas Best | MLB     |      2 |   199 |
| Econo Lodge   | SFB     |      1 |   209 |
+---------------+---------+--------+-------+
```

Expected results:

Selected hotel: Americas Best

```
+---------------+-------+---------+--------+-------+
|  hotel_name   | order | airport | people | price |
+---------------+-------+---------+--------+-------+
| Days Inn      | 1     | ..      | ..     | ..    |
| Holiday Inn   | 2     | ..      | ..     | ..    |
| Americas Best | Skip  | ..      | ..     | ..    |
| Econo Lodge   | 3     | ..      | ..     | ..    |
+---------------+-------+---------+--------+-------+
```

PHP/MySQL combination can be used for an answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does "around" mean?  SQL tables are inherently unordered.  So, please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: "Around" apparently means the next row with higher price plus the next two lower-priced rows relative to some "selected" row. This doesn't sound like a task you'd want to do in SQL though.

Comment: @shawnt00 Is this possible in PHP?

Comment: I was picturing a list of tickets/items with a couple of them highlighted. I was figuring that if you had already retrieved the full list then highlighting a couple of them would be better done in PHP. Maybe that doesn't quite match your needs though. I think the `limit 25` above was part of my impression but reading closer I see that that part doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @shawnt00 Changed to `limit 3` for clarity.

Comment: I think I just saw the 25 at a glance. You wouldn't really need to limit in the outer query at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 hours, I finally found the solution. I combined a union with two select queries that selects 3 rows before (and including the selected hotel) and 3 rows after the selected hotel. I then set `limit 3` and `order by price asc` and <strike>everything</strike> it mostly works.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   ( 
       ( 
            SELECT   * 
            FROM     temp_db_cart 
            WHERE    price >= {$package['price']} 
            AND      airport = '{$airport['abbr']}' 
            AND      people = '{$travelers['number-of-travelers']}' 
            ORDER BY price ASC limit 3 ) 
UNION 
         ( 
            SELECT   * 
            FROM     temp_db_cart 
            WHERE    price < {$package['price']} 
            AND      airport = '{$airport['abbr']}' 
            AND      people = '{$travelers['number-of-travelers']}' 
            ORDER BY price DESC limit 3 ) ) AS u 
WHERE    hotel_name != '{$package['hotel_name']}' 
ORDER BY price ASC limit 3;
```

**Edit**: The limiting of 3 rows in the parent select query only limits to the first 3 rows from the union set. How do I limit with an offset starting at 2 rows before the selected hotel and ending at 2 rows after the selected hotel of the union subset?

Answer (score 1):

You can `union` the two records with lower prices with the record of higher price:

```
select * from
(
(SELECT * 
  FROM temp_db_cart 
  WHERE airport='MCO' 
    AND people='3' 
    AND price < '245' 
  ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 3)
 UNION
(SELECT * 
  FROM temp_db_cart 
  WHERE airport='MCO' 
    AND people='3' 
    AND price > '245' 
  ORDER BY price LIMIT 1)
)
order by price desc limit 3
```

In the first query, you select 3 rows and in the second, 1 row (if it exists). Finally, Out of these `3+1` (or `3+0`) rows, you select only `3` rows with highest price.

Comment: The prices are dynamic so what if the current price is the highest amount in the table? How would the SQL query adapt to the new condition?

Comment: It wouldn't return any rows for the part of the query seeking rows that don't exist.

Comment: @Daniel, I edited the answer, I hope it solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
 FROM (SELECT MIN(price)
  FROM temp_db_cart 
  WHERE airport='$airport' 
    AND people='$people' 

    AND hotel != '$hotel'
  ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 3
 ) 
ORDER BY price ASC
```